# Hybris: Solr facet truncate Japanese words

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search, sap-commerce-cloud

I found a similar issue here.
[solr facet search truncate words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697897/solr-facet-search-truncate-words)

When I use solr facet for manufacturer name of products, then although the actual manufacturer name is like "化学商品", but in solr navigation area it shows up as two options: "化学" and "商品", which means it is stemming. For English manufacturer name it is working fine.

I cannot use fieldType string. I am using text.

How do I avoid it for Japanese characters so that it shows only the full manufacturer name. I also tried using the Tokenizer class CJKTokenizerFactory, but it didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use text for facets. If you wish to both search and facet on manufacturer name then extract this information twice, once as string and once as text and use these different representations in appropriate places.

Comment: Btw, could you please tell in Hybris, how can I keep data type of manufacturer name as string for search purpose, and text for facet purpose. Sorry I'm new to solr and also novice in Hybris.

Comment: just make 2 indexed properties

Comment: Yes I did that. I made "manufacturerName" solrIndexedProperty of type text and "manufacturerNameFacet" of type string. In solr's schema.xml I did, <copyField source="manufacturerName" dest="manufacturerNameFacet" />. On re-index, I get an error the field "manufacturerNameFacet" is missing. Any idea?